# SVM primal formulation: does the constants constraint matter?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

When finding the maximum margin separator in the primal form we have the quadratic program

$$min\frac{1}{2}||\theta||^2$$
$$\text{ subject to: } y^{(t)}(\theta \cdot x^{(t)} + \theta_0) \geq 1, \ t=1,...,n,$$

saying basically to find the maximum margin separator. The margin size will be:

$$\frac{1}{||\theta||}.$$

Does the size of the margin change if we change the constants of the constraint?

That is, if we have

$$\text{ subject to: } y^{(t)}(\theta \cdot x^{(t)} + \theta_0) \geq k, \ t=1,...,n,$$

instead of 1?

If it does not matter, why doesn't this matter? How is it an equivalent formulation regardless of the exact constants for the constraint?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the size of the margin will change, but we care about the direction more than the absolute size.

Suppose we solved the problem with $1$ as the lower bound and came up with $\theta$ and $\theta_0$. Then if we consider $k \theta$, $k \theta_0$ with $k \geq 0$ we satisfy the primal constraints with $k$ as a lower bound and the margin size will be $\frac 1 {k \| \theta \|}$. But this change isn't really meaningful, since we're still pointing in the same direction and have just made the vector a bit bigger or smaller.

In [Andrew Ng's course notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf) he refers to two kinds of margins, functional, where we care about the absolute distance of our points from the hyperplanes, and geometric, where we scale $\theta$ and $\theta_0$ by $\| \theta \|$ and then find the maximum distance under this constraint. One usually formulates the problem in terms of geometric margins but, through some transformations, you can show that a functional margin constrained to be 1, or really anything positive, is equivalent.

So by choosing $1$ as the functional margin we've just chosen a scaling of the direction that separates the points the best.